ruby-inotify unexpected tilde ~ added to some reported file names
I have a ruby script that runs waiting for a scanned pdf document to be uploaded to a path and then does some additional processing and notifications. The scanner is a Canon ImageRunner scanner using scan to an ftp path, the server runs a vsftpd with a very simple config.
require 'rb-inotify'

notifier = INotify::Notifier.new
notifier.watch("/root/test", :close_write) do |event|
    p event.absolute_name
    p event.name
end

notifier.run

Usually everything works as expected and we get back the file name & full path as expected.
"/root/test/doc1.pdf"
"doc1.pdf"
"/root/test/doc2.pdf"
"doc2.pdf"

But we have a new scanner device and when we scan a document from that machine the initial file names are reported with an additional ~ (tilde) appended to the end of the name (which breaks lots of things elsewhere in the processing script)
"/root/test/doc1.pdf~"
"doc1.pdf~"
"/root/test/doc2.pdf~"
"doc2.pdf~"

But when I check the actual folder the files are stored with the correct names and without the ~.
I'm guessing this is some weird issue with the way the new scanner actually writes the file to the server.
As a very quick and dirty hack I did a test removing the trailing ~ with [0...-1] from the path which superficially works, but breaks others things later in the bigger processing script.
What is the safest way I can work around this issue so that I only ever get the correct file name reported? (Just removing the last char isn't practical as manual uploads along with other scanners that might be used all return the correct filename, and in my dirty hack would end up as doc1.pd)

I cannot say in this specific case but Windows for instance uses a tilde ~ for temporary files (hidden) when the original is currently open for editing. I have also seen the tilde used for temporary files when a service is streaming to the file, which may be your issue. e.g. File is created, held open, data is streamed into the file, when the stream is complete the file is then closed and saved (sans the tilde).

Do the files have the trailing ~ for just a while (i.e. while they are being written)?  At a guess It may be that files like this are still being written and should not be read yet.

I'm not sure, its such a quick upload process and I've not dug that deep into it yet, but based on my thinking and what @engineersmnky said above I suspect the answer is yes... Is there a different watch flag I should be using to safely get around this problem? Oh I should just point out this is a Linux EL8 box! No windows here lol

Theoretically since you are watching "close_write" the file should have been written to and closed, however it seems that inotify might be slightly faster at notifying than the scanner process is at renaming or releasing the file. I am uncertain how best to overcome this condition. I guess possibly better than event.absolute_name[0...-1] would be something like event.absolute_name[/(.*[^~])/]

I'm not back in the office till Thursday (hopefully) so won't be able to test a lot till then, but yes I'm inclined to blame the new scanner and the way it writes a file. I am also thinking pure-ftpd may be an option as that apparently has pure-uploadscript which could solve the problem provided it doesn't suffer the same fate. Out of interest do you know how I could simulate this problem on a test machine? as in a temp file with a ~ before it becomes the 'real' file? I can at least test some other stuff if I can reproduce that issue locally.

@user3788685 seems like, based on the limited context of your post, you could just stub name to return a version with a tilde at the end.
